# How to convert JSON string Contains with double quote(") to table in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, database, postgresql

I would like to convert json string to table. Here my JSON string contains double quote(").
Below are sample code.

```
select * from json_to_record('{"id":1,"name":"John Smith - "JohnS@gmail.com""}' AS x(id int,name Text)
```

Here I would like get name : **John Smith - "JohnS@gmail.com"** in name column.
let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: we can use it with from clause as well. If json have multiple record then it will return multiple record in form of table. below query is working perfectly
select * from json_to_record('{"id":1,"name":"John Smith - JohnS@gmail.com"}') AS x(id int,name Text)

Comment: Surely that's not valid JSON; the quote in front of the email needs to be escaped otherwise it will be the closing quote of that field. To be valid the JSON should be: `'{"id":1,"name":"John Smith - \"JohnS@gmail.com\""}'`